# Can two entities in JPA have more than one relationship between them?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm, openjpa

let me define the following entities for example:

```
@Entity
public class Box{

    @ManyToOne
    Apple apple;

    @ManyToOne
    Orange orange;

}

@Entity
public class Apple {

    @OneToMany
    List<Box> boxes;

    @ManyToMany
    List<Orange> OrangeBoxMates;
}


@Entity
public class Orange {

    @OneToMany
    List<Box> boxes;

    @ManyToMany
    List<Apple> appleBoxMates;

}
```

Ignore the fact that many annotations have been omitted. I am just using this code as an example.

Now I want to create an additional unidirectional relationship between apples and oranges.

```
@Entity
public class Apple {

    @OneToMany
    List<Box> boxes;

    @ManyToMany
    List<Orange> OrangeBoxMates;

    @ManyToMany
    List<Orange> OrangeFriends;
}


@Entity
public class Orange {

    @OneToMany
    List<Box> boxes;

    @ManyToMany
    List<Apple> appleBoxMates;


}
```

Is there any reason I cannot do something Like this?

Comment: No, there's no reason. Just use the appropriate annotations and attributes, and everything will be fine.

Comment: Just to confirm, I cannot use the default names for the join columns because the default is the class name and there will be a collision. So If i make the join column names explicit (and different lol), everything will be fine?

Comment: Yes, everything will be fine.

Comment: This works, without custom names, in OpenJPA (from what i remember). However, the generated SQL is bizarre - there is a single join table with two columns for oranges. Not a very good design! Easily fixed with column annotations, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt Hibernate can tell the difference between the two `@ManyToMany` associations in `Apple` since you are using default join columns and these would be the same for both associations. I suppose you can customize your `Apple` associations to `Orange` so that they are mapped to different columns (different FKs) in the DB.